# Menu Index onKey Issue

Tags: c#, xna

Language: C#

Description: 
So currently I am making a small game in XNA. I am creating a menu for the game. I have 3 Menu Menu States. 1= Options Menu, 2= Start Menu, 3=Load Menu. So the goal is when the user presses the "D" key the menu index increments 1 and for the "A" key, the menu decrements. The problem with this is using the KeyDown in XNA is updating each Tick. So when I increment/decrement the index, it updates way to fast. I want the user to be able to switch menus without it flickering extremely fast. Below is my code, please let me know of any solutions.

```
if(keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
            {
                    LyEngine.Game.MENU_INDEX++;
                    if (LyEngine.Game.MENU_INDEX >= 3)
                    {
                        LyEngine.Game.MENU_INDEX = 1;
                    }

            }
            else if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
            {
                LyEngine.Game.MENU_INDEX--;
                if (LyEngine.Game.MENU_INDEX <= 1)
                {
                    LyEngine.Game.MENU_INDEX = 3;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the menu index when a key is down you need to capture the transition between a key being up on one tick and then the key being down on the next.

To do this, save the previous value of the key state and add it to your condition:

```
if(keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.D) && !keyWasDown[Keys.D])
{
    // ...
}
keyWasDown[Keys.D] = keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.D)
```

You'll have to create the dictionary `keyWasDown` to store the prior state.

Comment: For future use, instead of saving the single keys in a dictionary, just save the entire Keyboard State from the previous update. That way you won't have to make any changes when you suddenly want to start monitoring a new key.

Comment: Yes, @BjarkeSøgaard, that is a good refactor after it is working.

Comment: What about if I have multiple items though, not just 3?